# Is there a way to share a container's Tags and Triggers to another Container in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am using an web application which has multiple pages like,

```
www.myapp.com/a.html
www.myapp.com/b.html
www.myapp.com/c.html
```

I have configured a container for a.html in Google Tag Manager to capture the Click Events.
Is there any way that I can reuse these tags and triggers with another container. b.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the admin settings, you can export the container as a JSON file. You can then import the JSON into another container, and merge it with the existing configuration.  After the import, the containers are independent from each other and a change in one will not affect the others.

In the paid version of GTM you can use "[zones](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/guide-zones-google-tag-manager-360/)", basically attach a container to one or more other containers and share configuration that way.